# Stop a event from being executed while other is happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascriptmvc

I have a div and when I mouse over that particular div I have a SlideUP animation and on MouseOut i have a slideDown. When I mouseover and mouseout I want the SlideUp to happen completely and then mouseout event should be called.

I am using JavaScriptMVC architecture. Help me solve this.

Comment: Please show the relevant part of your JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic code for stopping events in javascript:

```
function doSomething(e)
{
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

For further information you can see the following pages:

1) [Event order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

2) [Event propagation order with controllers and filtered events.](http://forum.javascriptmvc.com/topic/event-propagation-order-with-controllers-and-filtered-events)